# How to take the derivative of a matrix with respect to itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Could someone please explain how to take the derivative of matrix with respect to itself?

$$\frac{\partial \textbf{X}}{\partial \textbf{X}}$$

where $\textbf{X}$ is an M x N matrix

Comment: What is your definition for this quantity?

Comment: Perhaps you mean finding Jacobian?

Comment: Maybe? I'm unsure as to what I'm doing

Comment: Interesting. I dont know. My intuition tells me that you would get the Identity matrix, but only if X were square. There might be a creative approach at resolution using the transpose.

Comment: What's the context of this question?

Answer (score 6):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$A matrix/matrix
gradient produces a 4th order tensor, which is easily evaluated in
index notation
$$\eqalign{
{\cal E} &= \p{X}{X} \quad\implies\quad
{\cal E}_{ijk\ell} &= \p{X_{ij}}{X_{k\ell}} &= \delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell} \\
}$$
where the Kronecker delta symbol is defined as
$$\eqalign{
\delta_{ik} &= 
\begin{cases}
{\tt1}\quad {\rm if}\;i=k \\
0\quad {\rm otherwise}
\end{cases}
}$$
In words:   If $X_{ij}$ and $X_{k\ell}$ refer to *different* elements then the derivative is $0$, otherwise it's $\tt1$.

This is analogous to the vector/vector derivative which produces the identity matrix
$$\eqalign{
I &= \p{x}{x} \quad\implies\quad
{I}_{ij} &= \p{x_i}{x_j} &= \delta_{ij} \\
}$$

Comment: Do you have a citation for this? Like a paper deriving this fact?

Answer (score 2):

The underlying mapping is
$$
f(X)=X,
$$
the identity mapping on the vector space $V$ of all matrices. It is linear, hence its derivative at $X$ in direction $\delta X$ is
$$
f'(X)\delta X=\delta X,
$$
which is
$$
f'(X) = f.
$$
Note, that both $f$ and $f'(X)$ are linear mappings from $V$ to $V$. 
The mapping $f'$ is a mapping from $V$ to $L(V,V)$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a lot easier than the previous posters are indicating
$\frac{d}{dX}(A*X)=A$
define $A=I_m$ where $m$ is the number of rows of $X$ because $I_m*X=X$ this is an identity and you get your derivative = $I_m$