# Derivative of symmetric inverse of a matrix

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices

I have an expression involving the inverse of a symmetric matrix, which I want to differentiate with respect to one of the elements of that matrix.  I've been working through the problem with help from the matrix cookbook ([https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)) but am unsure if I've correctly worked through - I'd be glad of advice as to whether the below is correct, that I have correctly adjusted for the fact that the matrix is symmetric.

(*This is for some algebra I am working out in order to implement the move step of an MCMC algorithm*)

I have an expression $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^{-1}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are both square matrices, and $\mathbf{B}$ is symmetric.  I want to evaluate the expression:

$\frac{d\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^{-1}}{dB_{gh}}$

Where $B_{gh}$ is the elementof matrix $\mathbf{B}$ in the $g$th row, $h$th colummn.

So far I have:

$\frac{d\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^{-1}}{dB_{gh}} = \{\frac{d\mathbf{A}}{dB_{gh}}\mathbf{B}^{-1}\}+\{\mathbf{A}\frac{d\mathbf{B}^{-1}}{dB_{gh}}\} $

With $\frac{d\mathbf{A}}{dB_{gh}}=\mathbf{0}$ as $\mathbf{A}$ doesn't contain any elements of $\mathbf{B}$.

Then, that

$\frac{d\mathbf{B}^{-1}}{dB_{gh}}= -\mathbf{B}^{-1}\frac{d\mathbf{B}}{dB_{gh}}\mathbf{B}^{-1}$

Then that as $\mathbf{B}$ is symmetric we have:

$\frac{d\mathbf{B}}{dB_{gh}}=Tr\{\{\frac{d\mathbf{B}}{d\mathbf{B}}\}^T \frac{d\mathbf{B}}{dB_{gh}}\}$

As $\mathbf{B}$ is symmetric, $\frac{d\mathbf{B}}{dB_{gh}}$ evaluates to $\mathbf{S}^{gh}$, where:

$\mathbf{S}^{gh}=\mathbf{J}^{gh}+\mathbf{J}^{hg}-\mathbf{J}^{gh}\mathbf{J}^{gh}$

Where $\mathbf{J}^{gh}$ is a matrix with a $1$ in the $g$th row and $h$th column, with $0$ elsewhere.

However, from this question ([How to take the derivative of a matrix with respect to itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040443/how-to-take-the-derivative-of-a-matrix-with-respect-to-itself)), am I correct in understanding that $\frac{d\mathbf{B}}{d\mathbf{B}}$ evaluates to $\mathbf{B}$?

Which would leave the solution to be the following?

$\frac{d\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^{-1}}{dB_{gh}}=-\mathbf{B}^{-1}\{\mathbf{B}\mathbf{S^{gh}}\}\mathbf{B}^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

$\def\v{{\rm vec}}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}\def\E{{\cal E}}$Let $F=AB^{-1}\,$ denote the matrix-valued function and calculate its differential.
$$\eqalign{
dF &= A\,dB^{-1} \\
 &= AB^{-1}\,dB\,B^{-1} \\
 &= F\,dB\,B^{-1} \\
}$$
At this point you have several choices.

If you are comfortable with tensors, then the fourth order identity tensor
$$\E = \p{B}{B} \quad\implies\quad
\E_{ijk\ell} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}$$
can be used rearrange the differential and extract the tensor-valued gradient
$$\eqalign{
dF &= F\E B^{-T}:dB \\
\p{F}{B} &= F\E B^{-T}
\;\;\in\,{\mathbb R}^{n\times n\times n\times n} \\
}$$
You can also use a Kronecker product to flatten the matrices into vectors and extract a matrix-valued gradient
$$\eqalign{
\v(dF) &= (B^{-T}\otimes F)\;\v(dB) \\
\p{\,\v(F)}{\,\v(B)} &= B^{-T}\otimes F
\;\;\in\,{\mathbb R}^{n^2\times n^2} \\
}$$
$\big[$NB: These first two approaches product *identical* components, but in different shapes.$\big]$

You could also define a set of indexed (single-entry) matrices by
$$\eqalign{
J_{ik} &= \p{B}{B_{ik}} \;=\; e_ie_k^T \\
}$$
where {$e_k$} are the standard basis vectors. Then substitute this directly into the differential expression to obtain
$$\eqalign{
\p{F}{B_{ik}} &= FJ_{ik}B^{-1} 
\;\;\in\,{\mathbb R}^{n\times n} \\
}$$
As for  the symmetry constraint, please read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773532). Afterward, if you still feel compelled to pursue the idea, then one common (but very misleading) interpretation is
$$\eqalign{
S_{ik} &= \p{B}{B_{ik}} 
\;=\; e_ie_k^T + e_ke_i^T - I\odot e_ie_k^T \\
\p{F}{B_{ik}} &= FS_{ik}B^{-1} 
\;\;\in\;{\mathbb R}^{n\times n} \\
}$$
where $\odot$ is the elementwise/Hadamard product and $I$ is the identity matrix.